# Does Intellisense work with objects extended with Ext.extend?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, extjs, intellisense, javascript

I can't get get Intellisense to display any methods other than Object methods when I inherit through Ext.extend().  Is it possible for Intellisense to display the additional methods?

I used the workaround suggested in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424183/javascript-intellisense-not-showing-everything/1431889#1431889) to get the namespaces working, so I don't believe that is related to this issue.

Example Code is below:

```
///<reference path="ext-base.js" />
///<reference path="ext-all.js" />
///<reference path="namespace.js" />
MNS.Production.DetailedGrid = Ext.extend(MNS.commonUI.GridPanel,
{
    initComponent: function () {
    var columns = this.getColumns();
    },

    getColumns: function () {
    var columns =
    //...build columns
    },
    //....
    //....Additional methods, etc.
});


var detailedGrid = new MNS.Production.DetailedGrid();
```

Although I get intellisense for the MNS.Production.DetailedGrid() command, I don't get any intellisense on the methods of the detailedGrid object, except default methods.  How do I get Visual Studio to show these methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that although there are [two ways to extend an object using ExtJS](http://ww.extjs.com/learn/Manual%3aIntro%3aInheritance), the only way that Intellisense will work with your code is if you use the following syntax:

```
///<reference path="ext-base.js" />
///<reference path="ext-all.js" />     
// create constructor for new class
Ext.ResizableConstrained = function(el, config){
    Ext.ResizableConstrained.superclass.constructor.call(this, el, config);
};

// extend the base class
Ext.extend(Ext.ResizableConstrained, Ext.Resizable, {
    setXConstraint : function(left, right){
        // Obtain a reference to parent dd property and setXConstraint
        this.dd.setXConstraint(left, right);
    },

   setYConstraint : function(up, down){
     // Obtain a reference to parent dd property and setYConstraint
     this.dd.setYConstraint(up, down);
   }
});
```

The /// references need to be at the top of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this MSDN post?
[MSDN Blog](https://web.archive.org/web/20111110014318/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdevtools/archive/2008/03/12/jscript-intellisense-working-with-ext-js.aspx)

Comment: That blog post mentions that the fix is for 2008, and would be patched for the next release.  Since I'm using 2010, I didn't expect it to work, but I tried it anyway with no luck.